# Extracting strings from unserialized object (PHP)

Tags: php, sql, arrays, serialization

I've unserialized an object in PHP which gives the below output. I'd like to extract the 2 URLs (or how ever many there will be) from the `[file_url]` index and store them into the database (by doing a `foreach` and then `INSERT INTO` via SQL?). Could anyone tell me the best way to achieve this? I've never worked with serializing/unserializing objects before.

```
Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [success] => 1
            [file_url] => Array
                (
                    [0] => https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/test1.png
                    [1] => https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/test2.jpg
                )

            [file_path] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/test1.png
                    [1] => /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/test2.jpg
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: The result is an array and you can access that value by the following code (I assumed that you stored this value in $var): `$var['file']['file_url']`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **indexes**. something like

`$value = $arr['file'][x][y]`

This is a **multidimentional** array. Its a 3 dimentional array to be exact.

**Examples**:

```
$value = $arr['file']['success']
$value = $arr['file']['file_path'][0]
```

You could **also** do

`$value = $arr['file'][0]`

Example of other dimentional arrays

```
$cars = array (
  array("Volvo",22,18),
  array("BMW",15,13),
);
```

### With SQL?

Sure, use PDO and bindParam for that crisp security

```
$query = $con->prepare("UPDATE nearly_inactive SET :email = :emailaddr WHERE EmailSent = :id");
$query->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':emailaddr', $emailaddr, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$update->execute();
```